# My Tags page is (still) showing no results on SO and Meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, meta, my-tags

I just visited https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged?tab=mytags and for me it shows no results. Has something broken?

The problem occurs for me [on meta too](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged?tab=mytags), but oddly not on some other sites I've tried, such as [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/unanswered/tagged?tab=mytags) or [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged?tab=mytags).

I have tried pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> many times, but as yet no success in solving this. **This has now been broken for days**, leading me to believe that caching is not the culprit.

I've since noticed that the problem goes away if I add some tags as favourites (e.g. [java](/questions/tagged/java)). But I prefer to have no favourite tags, so the problem remains for me. What's odd is that I don't use favourite tags anywhere on the network, so the fact that the ServerFault and Programmers tab works for me is a mystery.

---

[image: no results]